# React Hooks setState for Form Inputs works too slow to Post Method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I have a question as you can see on title of question. When my setState method updates my email input or password part, I am facing incorrect value. As an example, I am writing **123456** to password part , it sends **12345** when I click submit button. I know **handleInputChange** method makes render everytime, when I push any key. What should I do instead of this ? How can I solve that issue ?

My React Hooks Form Example :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const LoginPart = () => {
    const initialState: any = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
    };

    const [loginState, setState] = useState<any>(initialState);

    const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
        setState((prevState: any) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        }));
    };

    const handleSubmit: any = async (e: Event) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const user = {
                email: loginState.email,
                password: loginState.password,
            };

            exampleLoginPostMethod(user)
                .then((r: any) => {

                })
                .catch(

                );
        
    };

    return (
        <form className="form-part" onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(event)}>

            <div className="content-wrapper">
                <Input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    value={loginState.email}
                />
                <Input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    value={loginState.password}
                />
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    text={"login"}
                />
            </div>

        </form>
    );
};

export default LoginPart;
```

Comment: I saw other issues in this code, but the issue about the delay I believe is because of the "post Method" where you sending a stale state instead. Use the codesandbox to reproduce the issue as expected. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

React uses [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) while you have [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on the event value when using it within the `setState` callback, you will get a runtime error when the synthetic event will be reused and `e.target` will be `undefined`.

Therefore you should rewrite the logic without closures:

```
const initialState = {
  email: "",
  password: ""
};

const LoginPart = () => {
  const [loginState, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return ...
};
```

[image: Edit Q-65303599-syntEvents]

Comment: I don't know, it depends on the context. How it's related to the issue?

Comment: You have codesanbox example, use it to recreate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-65303599-syntevents-b0bxt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark as I already mentioned